# what if the S-boxes in DES were "optimal"

Tags: cryptanalysis, des, s-boxes, differential-analysis

if we assume that the s-boxes in DES were optimal. that is for each s-box, every cell in the DDT equals to 4. is there a differential characteristic in a good probability?

Comment: See [The Data Encryption Standard (DES) and its strength against attacks](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9c48/590ecfc31f6467c8dda3937ac441de44c3a2.pdf) by Don Coppersmith.